# SQL statement from 2 tables to 2 identical tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem figuring this one out, i have this SQL call, and this should be the primary one, now i also have 2 other 100% identical, book_program_times and book_programs, these 2 should be prefered IF there is any data to get, how in the world do i fix this the easiest way?
Thanks on behalf :D

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `program_times`,`programs` WHERE `programs`.`id` = `program_times`.`program_id` ORDER BY `hour`") or die (mysql_error());
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $arr[$r["hour"]][$r["day"]] = $r["title"];
    $arrid[$r["hour"]][$r["day"]] = $r["id"];
    $arrlive[$r["hour"]][$r["day"]] = $r["is_live"];
}
```

Comment: **Stop**  using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statement

Comment: If they are the same perhaps the data should be in a single table with an identifier column to discriminate the difference and allow for priority sorting.

Comment: Also **stop** using old style comma separated select, instead of joins.

Comment: Hmm-... 3 answers that are not useful, great.. :-)

Comment: @Jens gave you very useful suggestion to use `mysqli`, @AlexK. provided way for better data storing structure and I suggested for you to use `JOIN`s instead of comma-separated tables. I don't think that these suggestions are useless.

Comment: @UnknownGuard That are comments not answers. And all should be usefull for you to make better code

Comment: For a helpfull answer you should add the ddl of your tables, sample data and the excpected result. Most helpfull is a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: well, first of, converting from mysql_* til mysqli_* will not solve the problem... Second, the tables are as they are.. Third, maybe the join is better, and i will probably change it, BUT, the question is still, how can i check 2 tables for data, and use this, BUT, also check 2 other tables for data and prefer that data IF it exists... Really hard to explain...

Comment: @UnknownGuard Give us the needed informations and we will try to help you also with your problem

Comment: Thank you very much, how much information do you need?

Comment: @UnknownGuard only the ddl of your tables, sample data and the excpected result